# RSS memory increases while heap is stable in Node.js

Tags: node.js, memory

I've got a node.js application that supporting React server rendering with communicating internal server API.
BTW, application's RSS memory is increasing gradually.

I've been troubleshooting for 5 days now and already checked comparison of heap dump. But heap was stable. Only RSS was increasing.

```
2017-06-29 09:10:00 083: memoryUsage { rss: 107597824, heapTotal: 78532608, heapUsed: 68423584 }
2017-06-29 09:10:00 212: memoryUsage { rss: 107163648, heapTotal: 78532608, heapUsed: 67970768 }
2017-06-29 09:10:00 377: memoryUsage { rss: 106213376, heapTotal: 77484032, heapUsed: 67166800 }
2017-06-29 09:10:00 448: memoryUsage { rss: 106184704, heapTotal: 78532608, heapUsed: 62869512 }
....
....
2017-06-30 15:25:00 144: memoryUsage { rss: 140972032, heapTotal: 78532608, heapUsed: 65703576 }
2017-06-30 15:25:00 379: memoryUsage { rss: 135626752, heapTotal: 74338304, heapUsed: 64624224 }
2017-06-30 15:25:00 396: memoryUsage { rss: 139800576, heapTotal: 78532608, heapUsed: 66888688 }
2017-06-30 15:25:00 699: memoryUsage { rss: 140886016, heapTotal: 77484032, heapUsed: 67736488 }
2017-06-30 15:25:00 926: memoryUsage { rss: 142073856, heapTotal: 78532608, heapUsed: 67849096 }
```

At first, I thought that it causes from many client requests. However, today, I met huge traffic in short term. BTW, the RSS memory is not increased as much as traffic. It was strange.

I really wanna fix this issue. How and what should I do more?

```
Node.js version: 6.9.4
OS: RHEL 6.8
```

Memory Usage
[image]

Network Input
[image]

Comment: You can try to inspect your app: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector/. Use `--inspect` to launch and then open provided link in chromium-based browser. Possibly it will provide you with information about what consumes memory.

Comment: Also you can try to investigate heap dumps by opening them in chromium-based browser.

Comment: @vsenko I already checked with inspector and heapdump. But I couldn't find any problems. Also heap size is stable.

Comment: If RSS memory is increasing, then you should definitely notice that there are more items (JS objects or C memory allocations) of some kind. As far as I can see, memory consumption grows slowly, so you'll have to wait until you will be able to see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

if you're making http requests with `keepAlive` and a timeout, try a newer node.  There was a memory leak that affected v6.8 and v6.9, fixed in 6.10 (see https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/9440)

Edit: actually, if I remember right, that also affected heapUsed, not just rss.

Could you be leaking buffers?  Buffers are not on the heap, but do increase rss.

Comment: I created an issue on nodejs' github before. And the issue was fixed yesterday. Nodejs' crypto module has an memory issue. You can check here. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/13917